# html5 canvas is not showing full image

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

My image size is 940 * 300 but html5 canvas showing only part of image in chrome. Can you please help how to fix this?

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body onload="draw();">
        <p>Drag me</p>
        <canvas id="paint_area"></canvas>

        <script>
            function draw() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('paint_area').getContext('2d');

                //ctx.fillStyle = '#cc3300';

                var img_buffer = document.createElement('img');
                img_buffer.src = 'http://www.jobcons.in/homebanner.jpg';
                var imgWidth = img_buffer.width;
                var imgHeight = img_buffer.height;
                ctx.width = imgWidth;
                ctx.height = imgHeight;
                ctx.drawImage(img_buffer,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Two things:

- You were setting the context's size which doesn't make much sense. The *canvas* has a width and a height.
- You should really use `img_buffer.onload` to make sure you only paint the image when it's loaded and not before it's completely loaded.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/TpFQ8/

So:

```
<canvas id="paint_area" width="940" height="300"></canvas>
```

and:

```
var cv  = document.getElementById('paint_area'),
    ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
```

and:

```
img_buffer.onload = function() {
    var imgWidth = img_buffer.width;
    var imgHeight = img_buffer.height;
    cv.width = imgWidth;
    cv.height = imgHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(img_buffer, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
}
```

Comment: You need to change `ctx.width` to `ctx.canvas.width`.

Comment: even though canvas has fixed initial width & height ( 940x300) . So why resetting the width and height after onload is actually doing ? I have implemented this logic. Even the full image is now showing, but canvas is still (940x300). What is the logic behind this. Why the canvas visible dimension did not change ?  I thought that canvas width and height will vary according to uploaded image !

Answer (score 6):

The reason is simply that you **cannot** do

```
  ctx.width= imgWidth;
  ctx.height=imgHeight;
```

You must do

```
  can.width= imgWidth;
  can.height=imgHeight;
```

Where `can` is a reference to the canvas, and **not** the canvas context.

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rbNzb/

Comment: Note that you can get a reference to the canvas from the context with `ctx.canvas`.